# How to center content in a div in responsive skeleton?

Tags: html, css, centering, skeleton-css-boilerplate

There are similar questions to this but none of them are solving this problem.

I have built my site using a skeleton framework (http://www.getskeleton.com). For some reason, when i try to apply padding or any margin greater than 5px to the content in the main div on the site, the text portion jumps below the image. I've tried using their "offset-by" classes but the same thing happens. I've tried using

`margin:0 auto;` on all divs in that section but to no avail. I've also tried using `text-align:center;` but that didn't work either (oddly, this only centers the h1 element in that section but nothing else...).

The other issue I'm having is that I want all the backgrounds to expand to fit the width of the browser window and all the content should remain in the center but that doesn't seem to work well with this layout. If I set the container div's width to 100% it does expand but I end up having to set all the column and offset-by classes to 100% as well and then that messes up the navigation, etc. I want to keep my layout how I have it now but I just want the backgrounds to expand (including footer height) and for all content to be centered.

Here is the screenshot of what it looks like in the browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrRqn.png

Can anyone please take a look at the code and let me know what I should fix here? I've added my code on JSFiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/z9uVK/

Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: With a window width >959px, .container is 960px width and `#main` is 960px width. when you add margin to `#main` it reduces the width of `#main` e.g. with 5px margin #main is 950px width. `.one-third.column` has 20px total margin and 300px width, summing to 320px; `.two-third.column`  sums to 640px. thus 640px + 320px doesn't fit in the div once you add a margin. In your shoes I would probably just remove a few pixels of margin from `.column`

Comment: i don't quite understand what you want to do with backgrounds (none showing on jsfiddle) but you can probably apply css to the `html` or `body` element: `background-image:url('/foo.jpg');` and `background-size:contain;` to fit the element without overflowing or stretching.

Comment: by backgrounds I meant the colors behind header, main, and footer. Like the grey bar at top i want to expand across whole screen, the beige in middle i want to expand, and the purple in footer should expand.

Comment: Plato, in what instance should I remove pixels from .column? should I then make the width of container 100% and put #main as margin:0 auto? I tried all that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The skeleton is confusing the hell out of me, there is just so much going on... so I eliminated all CSS and added a few simple rules demonstrating the techniques I would use to code this behavior from scratch

Since you want the background color bands to extend beyond the container, I am setting the container to 100% and placing extra divs around each of header, main and footer. These have width 100% also. The width of `#header, #main, footer` is set to 960px by default and reduced with a media query. I have also set the columns and the headshot image to use percents instead of pixels. I also removed a couple inline style rules from the HTML because they were breaking this new code.

http://jsfiddle.net/W7wG3/1/

```
// part of my css:
.container{width:100%;}
#headerBin{ 
    background-color: white; 
    border-top: 15px solid #4d4d4d;
}

#header, footer, #main{
    width: 960px; 
    margin:auto; 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #header, footer, #main{
      width: 768px; 
      margin:auto; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.. although this does resize properly, removing the other parts of the skeleton framework messes up the layout I had. I copied everything over as you had it but kept the rest of the skeleton elements.. it did move the middle portion over somewhat but was still not in the middle and the header and footer were all shifted to the left. I'm able to get the backgrounds to extend by putting width at 100% but the middle portion never moves. That's really what I want to find out how to center, not change the layout so much that it breaks what I already had accomplished in the rest.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any easier way to get the backgrounds to extend beyond the width of their elements, than what I demonstrated above (wrapping them in their own containers, and setting the widths on the inner elements.) Hopefully someone with knowledge of the skeleton framework has a simple solution to fix the width problems for the stuff in #main. Have you considered contacting the skeleton developer and pointing him to this thread?

Comment: ping @CherryFlavourPez - they have multiple answers about skeleton, perhaps they can help?

Comment: Hey Pooja I made a small improvement: http://jsfiddle.net/VgAyc/ . I am not editing my post since it isn't using Skeleton but check it out - I am splitting your page into three `.container` divs, one for each of header, main and footer. Each is contained within a `.wide-container` set to 100% width. Basically the same as what I did in my answer, but without removing the skeleton code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, it definitely fixed the background colors expanding to fit the window! However, the content in "main" still isn't centered when expanded in a full browser window (here is the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/KNenTda.png). Would I need to add margin:0 auto to that? It seems like in the past when I did that it didn't make any difference. Let me know what you suggest. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Unless you have changed the CSS, the `.one-third` and `.two-thirds` divs are properly filling the entire width of their container div. You may want to remove the `width: 70%` attribute from `#intro`, and set `width: 33%; background-size: contain; background-image('some-square-solid-color.png')` on `#resume, #work, #skills`, and `text-align: center` on the `display:block` headers "Hello, a bit about me". remember to set `position: relative` on the containing div to ensure that the percentage widths work properly

Comment: there may be other ways to make `#resume, #work, #skills` fill the entire width, you could manually set the widths and heights, just make sure it sums up to the correct width for each layout

Comment: oh, if you want to keep the paragraph at `width: 70%`, `margin: 0 auto` should properly center it, as long as it's still a block element. You could also make a new div to contain the headers, square links, and paragraphs, and set that div's `width: 70%; margin: 0 auto;`, then remove `width: 70%` from the inner paragraph. That would move everything in `.two-thirds` to the right, centering that content within `.two-thirds`.

Comment: awesome, this last suggestion worked perfectly on the .two-thirds div. thanks! I still need to get the main image in .one-third to move over further though. do you think it's a good idea to use margins on that given it's a responsive design? not sure if that would mess everything up if people are on different size screens. I tried applying the same rule to the image that you suggested but it didn't do anything. applying a size to margin-left does work but i just wouldn't want to screw it up. let me know your thoughts.

Comment: Margins should be fine - but test it with each screen width (you should be able to resize the window, or the div on jsfiddle). and set different margins for the default, and each of the relevant mediaqueries in the skeleton css. that way you can customize the margins based on which of the several mediaqueries is active for that window width